# Looking for proper way to prioritize certain documents in Mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I was looking all over the place and I couldn't find a proper source for the problem I need to solve.

given record data, I need to prioritize some documents over others when I query all.

for example: lets say i'm doing this search

```
db.users.find().limit(10)
```

and my document has data with id = 1,2,3,....50;

how can I prioritize the query of id=12, or id=49 first?

what I would want to get back:

```
array({id=12}, {id=49} ... fill the rest until pager limit)
```

I tried using $or like this:

```
{
   "$or": [
     {'_id': {'$in': [id=12,id=49]}},
     {}
   ]
}
```

But I don't think this is the proper way of doing this and it's not working

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This will return only 12, 49 and I still want to get the rest (fill the array till the pager limit)

Comment: I know about skipping, this is not what I want.

I basically want to get all documents without any filtering (within the pager limit) but to make sure some values will be in the first page (sort them up to first page for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method,

- `$addFields` to add new fields for sorting purpose `hasId`, check condition if your field `_id` in your input ids then return 1 otherwise removes field
- `$sort` by `hasId` in descending order
- `$limit` documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      hasId: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: ["$_id", [8, 5]] },
          1,
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { hasId: -1 } },
  { $limit: 5 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pm5FddLDPfp)